# SQL join with pivot

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of tables i want to join. They are connected through a pivot table.

I have a `projects` table, a `employees` table and a pivot table called `employee_project` that has both a `project_id` and a `employee_id`:

| id | employee_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

I want to get the `first_name` and `last_name` from the `employees` table but the where clause should search in the `company_id` and `course_id` on the `projects` table.

So far i have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects
JOIN employees
     ON employees.id = employee_project.employee_id
JOIN employee_project 
     ON projects.id = employee_project.project_id 
WHERE course_id = 3 AND company_id = 150004
```

But this obviously isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your query is that you're using `employee_project` table before joining it. I just changed the order of join and it seems working!

```sql
SELECT
    employees.first_name,
    employees.last_name 
FROM
    projects
    JOIN employee_project ON projects.id = employee_project.project_id
    JOIN employees ON employees.id = employee_project.employee_id 
WHERE
    projects.course_id = 3 
    AND projects.company_id = 150004;
```

This should give you the `first_name` and `last_name` of employees who are associated with projects that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

you should join employee_project table first, and then join employees table

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
JOIN employee_project  ON projects.id = employee_project.project_id  
JOIN employees ON employees.id = employee_project.employee_id 
WHERE course_id = 3 AND company_id = 150004 ;
```